# Web view making stop to controller of exoplayer in ViewPager Android

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I am working on dynamic view pager Android and I set the code on onPageSelected method and checking mime type ,if mime type contains web and next index contains video it working perfect but controller for video player not able to click in this case.Please let me know the solution ,I will appreciate for your help

Comment: if (timeLineModelArrayList.get(currentPos).getMime_type().equalsIgnoreCase("video")) {
                        mnextFragment.closeexoplayer();
                        mnextFragment.initializePlayer();

                    }

                    else if(timeLineModelArrayList.get(currentPos).getMime_type().equalsIgnoreCase("web")) {
                        mnextFragment.closeexoplayer();
                        mnextFragment.callwebmime();

                    }

Comment: public void callwebmime(){
        view_mime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        playerView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCacheEnabled(true);
        webView.getSettings().setAppCachePath(mcontext.getCacheDir().getPath());
        webView.getSettings().setCacheMode(WebSettings.LOAD_DEFAULT);
        webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        getWebview(Card_url);



    }

Comment: public void initializePlayer() {
        view_mime.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        playerView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        BandwidthMeter bandwidthMeter = new DefaultBandwidthMeter();

         
        }